# Ejecutar otra función después de un determinado tiempo c#

Tags: c#, hilos

Tengo un script en python que hace un request SOAP pero toma el valor de la tabla en la db, pero ahora quisiera hacer que cuando termine con ese cliente pase al siguiente es algo que no se como, a este lo mando llamar desde un aplicación en Windows Forms

Con un boton mando llamar al tick del timer

```
private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Funciones f = new Funciones();
    ThreadStart delegado = new ThreadStart(f.DatosEnvio);
    //f.DatosEnvio();
    Thread hilo = new Thread(delegado);
    hilo.Start();
}
```

Luego en una clase tengo la consulta

```
public void DatosEnvio()
{
   string cnn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["prueba"].ConnectionString;
   using (SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(cnn))
   {
      conexion.Open();
    
      int rest = 0;
      //string consulta = "SELECT Nombre,Empresa FROM SamsaraVehiculos WHERE Disponible=1 AND Folio > 0 AND Empresa <> ''";
      string consulta = "SELECT Nombre,Empresa FROM SamsaraVehiculos";
      using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(consulta, conexion))
      {
         cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
         SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    
         try
         {
            while (rd.Read())
            {
               string Vehiculo = rd["Nombre"].ToString();
               //string Empresa = rd["Empresa"].ToString();
    
               //if (Empresa == "Transplace")
               //{
               string path = Application.StartupPath + "\\InterfazAssistCargo\\";
    
               string[] Valores = { Vehiculo, path };
               Thread hilo = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(Automatico));
               hilo.Start(Valores);
               Thread.Sleep(2000);

               // Lo que quisiera hacer es que cuando termine 
               // con todos estos valores pase a esta siguiente 
               // introducir el código aquí

               string path2 = Application.StartupPath + "\\InterfazQS3\\";
    
               string[] Valores2 = { Vehiculo, path };
               Thread hilo2 = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(Automatico));
               hilo.Start(Valores2);
               Thread.Sleep(2000);
    
               //}
            }
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             rest = 99;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Es algo que aun no se, estoy usando hilos pero igual es algo tardado, agradezco cualquier idea

Comment: A que viene la etiqueta "python-3.x"?

Answer (score 0):

Bien, si comprendo lo que quieres realizar es llamar a la función Automatico pasandole Valores y cuando termine, llamarla otra vez pasandole Valores2 y todo eso dentro del loop.

Esto lo podrías trabajar con Tasks:

```
private async void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Funciones f = new Funciones();
   await f.DatosEnvioAsync();
}
```

Dentro de la clase Funciones:

```
public async Task DatosEnvioAsync()
{
   string cnn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["prueba"].ConnectionString;
   using (SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(cnn))
   {
       conexion.Open();

       int rest = 0;
       string consulta = "SELECT Nombre,Empresa FROM SamsaraVehiculos";
       using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(consulta, conexion))
       {
          cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
          SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();

          try
          {
             List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
             while (rd.Read())
             {
                string Vehiculo = rd["Nombre"].ToString();
                string path = Application.StartupPath + "\\InterfazAssistCargo\\";
                string path2 = Application.StartupPath + "\\InterfazQS3\\";

                string[] Valores = { Vehiculo, path };
                string[] Valores2 = { Vehiculo, path };

                // La función 'IntroducirValores' usará la variable 'Valores' y cuando termine, 
                // se ejecutará 'IntroducirValores' pero usando Valores2
                var task = IntroducirValoresTask(Valores)
                                .ContinueWith(t => IntroducirValoresTask(Valores2));

                // Inicializa la task y la agrega a la lista
                // El thread principal ( que está leyendo rd.Read()) continuará y no esperará a que 
                // se termine de ejecutar IntroducirValores(Valores) e IntroducirValores(Valores2)
                task.Start();
                tasks.Add(task);
                     
             }

             // Aquí se espera a que todo termine
             await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
              rest = 99;
          }
       }

    }
 }

// Función que crea una Task que llama a la función Automatico 
private Task IntroducirValoresTask(string[] pValores)
{
   string[] valores = pValores;

   return new Task(async () =>
   {
       Automatico(valores);
       await Task.Delay(2000);
   });
}

private void Automatico(string[] valores)
{
   // Aquí realizas lo que gustes.
   // Asegurate que sea thread safe ya que varios threads podrían mandar a llamar a esta función.
}
```

De esta manera en cada iteración inicializas una task (que ejecutará la primera función y esperará dos segundos y después ejecutará la segunda función), pero que no bloqueará al thread principal por lo que se seguirá iterando y por lo tanto inicializando tasks. Una vez que salga del ciclo while, esperará a que todas las tasks hayan finalizado para salir de DatosEnvioAsync.

Si quisieras esperar por cada iteración podrías eliminar tasks y esperar a que se termine las task:

```
...
while(rd.Read())
{
  ...
  // task.Start();
  // tasks.Add(task);

  await task;
}
...
```